# How to mock the return data in the unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the below code

```
Class A {
    public boolean showData() {
        NewData data = getNewData();
        if (data!=null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public NewData getNewData () {
        return NewData = abc;
    }
}
```

I need to mock getNewData to return the mocked data, when I call showData().

To be clear,

if I mock the getNewData like below,

```
when(a.getNewData()).thenReturn(null);
assertFalse(showData()) // this doesn't work because the mocked internal getNewdata is not used.
```

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what mocking framework are you using?

Comment: Can you show more of the test, including the mock setup?

Comment: And in that specific case, it would make sense to have a constructor in A that takes a NewData - that way you can test easily... In other words, try to make your class more testable before using mocks which should be a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to test A.showdata, you can derive a class from A that overrides getNewData which returns whatever you need for testing.  It's a technique known as 'subclass and override'.

EDIT:  In pseudocode, you do the following:

```
Class B: public A {
    public NewData getNewData () {
       return <whatever you need for your test>
    }
}
```

Now, to test A.showData, you do the following:

```
B mySut = new B();
Bool result = mySut.showData();  // this calls A.showData, which calls B.getNewData.
```

Comment: can you provide me an example pleae

Comment: Added a bit of example pseudocode.  In any case, you shold search the web for 'subclass and override' for more and better examples.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to inject NewData into the method as a parameter

showData(data) and have the class/method that calls showData use getNewData()

When mocking, dependency injection is the general answer to issues (in my experience). This allows you to pass in the exact NewData you want the method to use and therefore mock.

Comment: I don't want to change the existing code, is there a way to do it without changing the code